# Mentor Mentee matching system in Google Sheets

Tags: python, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have data collected from a form filled by two parties - mentors and mentees. A mentor fills a form with details with attributes like skill, designation, timezone and a mentee fills out the form with preferences like preferred skill to learn and preferred timezone again bearing weightage.

I want to build a matching system where I match a mentor with a mentee. There are a couple of conditions -

1. A mentor shouldn't be mapped with more than two mentees
2. The match should be a percentage value

I'd prefer the solution to be in Google sheets. Thanks for any suggestions or advice.

Tried this formula but didn't work as expected

`

=ArrayFormula(

IFERROR(

```
IF(

  ROW($A:$A)=1,

  "Match %",

  IF(

    COUNTIF($B$2:$B$4,$A2)<=2,

    MAX(

      FILTER(

        $B$2:$B$4,

        COUNTIF($J$1:J1,$B$2:$B$4)<2

      )=$B$2:$B$4

    )*

    SUMPRODUCT(

      B2:E2,

      {0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1},

      $G2:$H2,

      {0.6, 0.4}

    )/

    (

      SQRT(SUMSQ(B2:E2))*

      SQRT(SUMSQ($G2:$H2))

    ),

    ""

  )

)
```

)

)

`

Adding a doc for input and output reference: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jRtryAP8IyhxZRApfklv43jPmtQDbT97jtLDi0B-yPY/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Hello, I suggest you upload more information about how your data is organised and how you expect the matches to be. Maybe some kind of sorting would work, but I don't know if you'd be able to do it only with formulas. It depends on your dataset and conditions

Comment: Thanks for the response @Martín. I've added the doc in the question.